# How do you check constraints from another table when entering a row into a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have two tables Account and Withdraw.
Account has an attribute Balance.
Every time a value is entered into the table Withdraw I would like to check if there is sufficient balance to do so. If yes, I'd like to subtract that amount from the Balance.

This isn't exactly what I want to do, but a simplified version of my requirement.

PS: Is "check constraints" the correct phrase? I'm not really sure. Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far? We're here to help you learn yourself, not write the code for you! Please and thanks :)

Comment: Yes check constraint is the answer :) search on that !

Comment: @jbutler483 So far all my searches have come with results that help me check if the withdrawal is less than a certain fixed value.

Comment: So, realistically, you're going to (possibly) have to read the users balance from the db, check if it's enough, then subtract if accepted and *then* write it to your db. That sound ok? that way you can also notify the user if it was accepted/declined quickly enough

Comment: Yes, but how do I perform checks? I really wish I could use if's here! :(

Comment: Are you just writing in sql? or are you using winforms/c# as well?

Comment: I've just started learning SQL. So I'm not using it with anything else for now. I will be using it with Python later.

Comment: have a look at this: SQL allows *if* logic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms182717.aspx . The next link will show you how to tell if it is greater than another element in the db: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211774/sql-constraint-that-one-column-value-cannot-be-greater-than-another-in-a-differe

Answer (score 0):

This is short example:

```
INSERT INTO mytable 
            (id, name) 
SELECT 1, 'test' 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT id 
                  FROM   myanother_table 
                  WHERE  id = 1)
```

> **Note:** Its hard to assume anything without understand or taking a look
>   of OP's code. So i have just provided example.

Comment: not sure this is excatly what the OP is looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function where you verify if the balance is > than your @value.
And then you add that function to the constraint.

Try to look at this:

[Can a Check constraint relate to another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880698/can-a-check-constraint-relate-to-another-table)

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting not a constraint.  You're looking for a trigger.  Take a look at this example.

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    sys.objects
            WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Account]')
                    AND type IN ( N'U' ) )
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Account]
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Account
    (
      AccountID INT NOT NULL ,
      AccountBalance DECIMAL(19, 2) NOT NULL
    )
GO

IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    sys.objects
            WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Transaction]')
                    AND type IN ( N'U' ) )
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Transaction]
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.[Transaction]
    (
      TransactionID INT NOT NULL
                        IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      AccountID INT NOT NULL ,
      TransactionAmount DECIMAL(19, 2) NOT NULL
    )
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TRI_Transaction ON dbo.[Transaction]
    AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE  a
    SET     a.AccountBalance = a.AccountBalance + i.TransactionAmount
    FROM    Account a
            JOIN INSERTED i ON ( a.AccountID = i.AccountID )
GO

INSERT  INTO dbo.Account
        ( AccountID, AccountBalance )
VALUES  ( 1234, 0 )

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Account a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Transaction] t ON ( a.AccountID = t.AccountID )

INSERT  INTO dbo.[Transaction]
        ( AccountID, TransactionAmount )
VALUES  ( 1234, 10 )

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Account a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Transaction] t ON ( a.AccountID = t.AccountID )


INSERT  INTO dbo.[Transaction]
        ( AccountID, TransactionAmount )
VALUES  ( 1234, 20 )

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Account a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Transaction] t ON ( a.AccountID = t.AccountID )

INSERT  INTO dbo.[Transaction]
        ( AccountID, TransactionAmount )
VALUES  ( 1234, -15 )


SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Account a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Transaction] t ON ( a.AccountID = t.AccountID )
```