# Foreign keys in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a doubt about the way of relating some tables. I have these tables:

- User table: username (primary key)
- Team table: team_name(primary key), username (foreign key references User(username))

With this relationship, I get that an user can have more than one team.

- Group table: group_name (primary key)

I want that a group can have many teams, but these teams have to be of different users, so two teams of a user cannot be in the same group.

I have thought to do a relationship with the three tables of this way:

- Group_teams table: (group_name, username, team_name). This table would have a composite primary key (group_name and username), in this way I would be sure that an user cannot has more than one team in a same group.

In addition, I think that I should create a composite foreign key references User(username) and Team (team_name) to be able to control that the team of a user exists. Finally, I should create another foreign key references Group (group_name) to control that a group exists.

I'm not sure that it would be of this way because I have errors when I try to do it. Could yo help me and tell me your opinions?

Comment: I removed the superfluous database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

If a user can be on (at most) only one team, then you have a 0/1 - many relationship.

The easiest approach is to have `TeamId` in the `Users` table.  This would be a foreign key reference to `Teams`.

There is no need for a third table to represent this relationship.

Comment: Yeah I was going to say the same +1

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff and minigeek,

I have not explained well...

A user can control one or many teams, but this team only is controlled by this user. The condition is that a group can have many teams of different users, but a group cannot have more than one team of the same user. 

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to reproduce the `username` field in the `Group_teams` table, just have `group_name` & `team_name`.

Create a trigger on the `Group_teams` table to fire before a new row is inserted, checking for more other teams with the same `username`.

Have a look at the question "[How do you check constraints from another table when entering a row into a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869230)", specifically [this answer from Jim V](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25870017/243925) describing such a setup.